# how to set tooltip width auto adjust in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, width

im using simple bootstrap tooltip but content is too long plz help me how can i adjust auto width of tooltip in bootstap

here is my code`

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Enter your emergency point of contact who may be a person in or outside of the United States, e.g., a family member, friend, or business associate.
In the Family Name field, enter your emergency contactï¿½s family name. You must complete this field to complete the application. If you have no emergency contact, enter UNKNOWN.
In the First (Given) Name field, enter the emergency contact first name. You must complete this field to complete the application. If you have no emergency contact (or your contact has only one name), enter UNKNOWN."></i>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap 4.1 you can modify the max-width value of .tooltip-inner class, for example:

```
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 500px !important;
}
```